# What am I missing here? Simple for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm quite new with python and I'm trying something very basic but I don't seem to get the desired result.
The final goal is to send a few API calls to an endpoint by populating different details.
I have a list of items I need to do something with them, the actions that need to be applied to them are different values contained in a CSV, I've figured out how to handle the different parameters and fill in in the API call properly, now I need to iterate all rows on the CSV, with their relevant parameters, over a list of items.

So I have a text file with items that looks like this:

1234
5678
3333
5555
etc...

And a CSV file with different columns that represent different parameters

Here's the code I wrote:

```
items_file = 'itemlist.txt'
action_file = 'actions.csv'

file_handle = open(action_file, "r", encoding="utf8")
csv_reader = DictReader(file_handle)

with open(items_file, "r") as myfile:
    item_list = myfile.read().splitlines()


def actions(arg_item_list):
    for item in range(len(arg_item_list)):
        for row in csv_reader:
            print('do something with ' arg_item_list[item]) 
            blah 
            blah...
            

actions(item_list)

file_handle.close()
```

The problem I'm facing is that it seems to run fine on the first item, and if I ask to print the list of items and actions it will print them fine, but when running the actual actions of sending each row params on a call for each item, it only runs on the first one and exits.

So it does what I want but only on "1234" which is the first line of the text file, all the others are not getting into the nested loop.

I know I'm missing something very basic, and I'll appreciate your kind help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The csv.DictReader object is an iterator, and iterators can only be iterated over once, then they're "spent".

(And by the way, your outer loop can probably be simplified to

```
for item in arg_item_list:
    do_stuff_with(item)
```

if you need the index too, you can do

```
for index, item in enumerate(item_list):
    print("item number", index, "is", item)
```

This saves you some range(len()) and [] drill.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ture Pålsson for the hints, I understood the "disposable" character of the DictReader object, so I've researched this further to find a viable way to be able to reuse it as much as I can.
I've found that if I convert this to a table and populate all rows with columns names and values I'm able to iterate over it similarly to what I did just as many times as I want.
Here's the final code:

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
from typing import List, Dict


items_file = 'itemlist.txt'
action_file = 'actions.csv'

file_handle = open(action_file, "r", encoding="utf8")
csv_reader = list(DictReader(file_handle))
table: List[Dict[str, str]] = [] #in my case, all values were strings, but you could use this also to convert it to other types, e.g. List[Dict[str, float] = [].

with open(items_file, "r") as myfile:
    item_list = myfile.read().splitlines()


for row in csv_reader:
    str_row: Dict[str, str] = {} 
    for column in row:
        str_row[column] = str(row[column])
    table.append(str_row)


def actions(arg_item_list):
    for item in arg_item_list:
        for row in table:
            print('apply actions from columns data on rows by their name e.g. ', row['action_column_1'], row['any_other_column_name']
            print('and apply them on ' arg_item_list[item]) 
            

actions(item_list)

file_handle.close()
```

I hope someone finds this useful!